# node daemon won't start with process.stdin.setRawMode(true)

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, daemon

I am running a node server daemon but I keep running into this error.

When I run my bash strip to test the application I get `TypeError: process.stdin.setRawMode is not a function`.

Can you help me find a way I can use keyboard input with this node application running in the background?

I have tried giving my bash script permissions `chmod 777 x.sh` & `chmod 755 x.sh`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`setRawMode()` is only available when the input is provided by a TTY and not like yours as direct stream from `stdin`.

Use this to check what stream you have:

```
if (process.stdin.isTTY) {
    process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
}
```

Comment: thank you @DanFromGermany, this solved my problem. The server works in both scenerios in the background as daemon and off of command. Although the background server can't take the special keyboard input. This make sense becasue you can't access the commandshell to input the special keystrokes.

Comment: Your last sentence is unnecessarily snarky. This is the top google result.

Comment: @dwjohnston It wasn't in 2018, but I agree and removed the unnecessary sentence.