# Listening for user input in Node.js, but also handling Ctrl-C for child processes

Tags: node.js, linux, macos, selenium-webdriver

I have a Node.js application that launches Chrome via ChromeDriver. When the user presses <kbd>Q</kbd>, I want to cleanly exit the application, shut down the ChromeDriver, and quit the main process. The same should work for <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>, except that I may not run some special cleanup routines in that case.

Here is a minimal reproducible example (you only have to `npm i selenium-webdriver` to run this, assuming you have Chrome and ChromeDriver installed):

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

const webdriver = require("selenium-webdriver");
const chrome = require("selenium-webdriver/chrome");

console.log("Start");

const options = new chrome.Options();
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");

const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .forBrowser("chrome")
  .setChromeOptions(options)
  .build();

driver.get("https://www.google.com");

const exit = (signal) => {
  console.log("Exit via " + signal);
  if (signal == "quit") {
    console.log("Doing some cleanup before quitting");
  } else {
    console.log("Exiting immediately");
  }
  driver && driver.quit();
  process.exit(0);
};

const { stdin } = process;
stdin.setRawMode(true);
stdin.resume();
stdin.setEncoding("utf8");

stdin.on("data", async (key) => {
  if (key.toString().trim() === "q") {
    exit("quit");
  } else if (key.toString().trim() === "\u0003") {
    exit("CTRL-C");
  }
});

console.log(
  "Waiting for input. Press Q to quit normally or Ctrl-C to exit immediately."
);
```

When I press Q, it exits the runs the cleanup routine, then quits the driver, and then exits.

Yet, when I press <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>, it exits the main process but **does not quit the driver.** It stays open and I have to manually close it.

Why is the `driver.quit()` method not working when I press <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>?
How can I get it to work?
Are there any other ways I might be able to replicate the default behavior of <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> when also listening for arbitrary user input?

Note: I am aware that setting raw mode for the input disables handling of the `SIGINT` kill signal, and consequently, I have to handle it myself. The main quirk is that `exit` in the case of a `q` keypress works fine, but for Ctrl-C it does not.

This has been run on Node.js 18 under macOS 13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the process terminated before the driver quit completed.

This is normally handled by using `await` in a Selenium JS tests:

`after(async () => await driver.quit());` such as the one found here: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/first_script/

[image: Selenium / JS]

In your concrete example, modify the `exit` function as follows:

```js
const exit = (signal) => {
  console.log("Exit via " + signal);
  if (signal == "quit") {
    console.log("Doing some cleanup before quitting");
  } else {
    console.log("Exiting immediately");
  }

  if (!driver) {
    return process.exit(0);
  }

  driver.quit().then(() => {
    console.log("Driver quit");
    process.exit(0);
  });
};
```

---

It's still possible to accomplish the same goal without using `await` if you have another way to make sure the driver has finished quitting before the program terminates...

I've modified your code so that pressing <kbd>Q</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> quits the driver, and pressing <kbd>E</kbd> or <kbd>X</kbd> exits the program. Here, the driver will quit normally if you press <kbd>Q</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> first, before pressing <kbd>E</kbd> or <kbd>X</kbd> to exit the program.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env node

const webdriver = require("selenium-webdriver");
const chrome = require("selenium-webdriver/chrome");

console.log("Start");

const options = new chrome.Options();
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");

const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .forBrowser("chrome")
  .setChromeOptions(options)
  .build();

driver.get("https://www.google.com");

const quit = (signal) => {
  console.log("Exit via " + signal);
  console.log("Closing the driver!");
  driver && driver.quit();
};

const exit = (signal) => {
  console.log("Exit via " + signal);
  console.log("Exiting the program!");
  process.exit(0);
};

const { stdin } = process;
stdin.setRawMode(true);
stdin.resume();
stdin.setEncoding("utf8");

stdin.on("data", async (key) => {
  if (key.toString().trim() === "q") {
    quit("Quit - Q");
  } else if (key.toString().trim() === "\u0003") {
    quit("CTRL-C");
  } else if (key.toString().trim() === "e") {
    exit("Exit - E");
  } else if (key.toString().trim() === "x") {
    exit("Exit - X");
  }
});

console.log(
  "Press Q or Ctrl-C to quit the driver. Press E or X to exit the program."
);
```

Essentially, make sure the `exit` part does not start until **AFTER** the driver `quit` completes.

Comment: When I try this modified with Q, I get `Closing the driver!`, the driver quits, and then the program never exits. Your first suggestion worked though; I added the exit in `driver.quit().then(() => process.exit(0))`.

Comment: The only challenge remaining is that when I don't use raw mode, pressing Ctrl-C also kills the driver immediately (I assume because the signal is being forwarded to all child processes). I cannot replicate this with the "manual" approach, where I have to wait for the driver to quit and otherwise cannot kill it. Or can I?

Comment: Regarding raw mode, this info may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53050098/7058266 . The 2nd example in my solution divided the quit/exit into two parts. First Q / Ctrl-C for the driver and E / X for the program. But using `driver.quit().then(() => process.exit(0))` did both actions together successfully for me.

Answer (score -1):

The moment you press CTRL+C, the program terminates, thus no more of your code will be read. However, you can add a event listener to the process and interrupt the CTRL+C.

**Add the following to listen for CTRL+C**

```
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
    //perform your cleanup work

    //then when your ready, you can perform the exit.
    process.exit();
});
```

Comment: It's raw mode so ctrl-c does not send sigint to the process

Comment: Yes, exactly, this would've been the default behavior, but due to raw mode it doesn't work. I did create a minimal reproducible example for this particular case, so please run the code and attempt your solution there, you'll see it won't work.

Comment: @slhck - I ran it on my machine and everything worked as expected for both the Q key and CTRL-C. Node 19.7.0 on Windows.  When you press CTRL-C, does it immediately end or does it print the "Exiting immediately" to your console before closing? If you not seeing the logged lines before it closes, the SIGINT seems to still working.  If you DO see your log lines, I think there is a possible race condition.  Try placing process.exit() inside a timeout() to ensure driver quits. Also try disabling rawMode via stdin.setRawMode(false) before driver.quit().

Comment: I do see the log lines `exiting immediately` when pressing Ctrl-C. When you set raw mode, STDIN is not captured (any handler set for it will not fire). I cannot disable raw mode, because I want to capture `Q` as it is pressed. (When you disable raw mode the user has to press Q and Enter for it to be captured.)

Comment: I should add that Windows handles signals completely differently compared to Unix, and Node.js abstracts that away when using Windows (https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/5054). So manually handling these signals under Windows works differently. I am looking for a *nix solution.